# How to call User Control from one of the Javascript function?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, user-controls, highcharts

I am using High-chart where in,a Graph is plot with different points. When I click on a point, I am supposed to call a user-control ? How shall I call a user control?

Below is the function of High-chart

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
           cursor: 'pointer',
           events: {
            click: function(event) {
                         CreateFailureTrendForDevice(pointVal);
                   }
                }
             }
```

CreateFailureTrendForDevice is a function in JS initially I used to use Ajax to Plot another graph but now I want to use Usercontrol ...

Comment: What you mean User Control?after click, what should be done / triggered?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I have understand you exactly, javascript code in User Controls are global code in the whole DOM of aspx pages.

Comment: Actually I want to invoke User Control from JS Function ,JS Function resides inside .JS file from there I want to call a user Control...